# How to get variables from a function to another function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple `Tkinter` user registration app and have run into a problem. I want to get the input from an `Entry` to another function.

My code as of now:

```
from Tkinter import *

def addUsr():
    username = sv.get()              #here
    password = sv1.get()             #here
    page = open("Users.txt", 'r+')
    contents = page.read()
    page.write("--->")
    page.write("\n")
    page.write("username: " + username) 
    page.write("\n")
    page.write("password: " + password)
    page.write("\n")
    page.write("<---")
    page.write("\n")
    page.close()
    print contents


def reg():
    usrs = Tk()
    usrs.title("Text")
    usrs.geometry('450x300+200+200')
    sv = StringVar()
    sv1 = StringVar()
    ent1 = Entry(usrs, textvariable=sv).pack()
    ent2 = Entry(uses, textvariable=sv1).pack
    button1 = Button(usrs, text="submit", command=addUsr).pack(side='bottom', padx=15, pady=15)
    usrs.mainloop()
```

I want to get the `sv` and `sv1` into the `addUsr` function, but this code returns the error message:

```
username = sv.get()
NameError: global name 'sv' is not defined
```

When the code is built up so that the second function is not a function this code works. I just want to find a way to get the same result but using this structure. How do you suppose I do this?

Comment: Yes, `sv` isn't defined inside that function. Also, note that in one place you assign the *return* from `pack`, and in another you don't even call it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a structural problem. You normally would use a class to create the application and put everything under that class. Then accessing functions and variables from anywhere is straightforward. I have created a simple example because I do not have time to rewrite all of your code!

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame): # create a class to hold the application within

    def __init__(self, master): # boot it up
        """ Initialize the frame. """
        Frame.__init__(self, master) 
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.var1 = "var1"
        self.var2 = "var2"

    def create_widgets(self): # create the GUI interface

        self.lbl = Label(self, text = "xxxx")
        self.lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W, pady = 4)
        self.input = Text(self, width = 35, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.input.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
        self.submit_button = Button(self, text = "submit", command = self.functionX)
        self.submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    def functionX(self):

        print "do some stuff"
        self.var3 = "yet another variable" # create a variable in one function for access in another
        self.functionY() # call one function from another function

    def functionY(self):

        print "do something else"
        print self.var1 # access some class variables
        print self.var2
        print self.var3

root = Tk() 
root.title("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
root.geometry("330x310")
app = Application(root)
```

I hope this helps, it is pretty self explanatory when you run the code and read it to understand what is going on. (by the way I ended up using PyQt/Pyside with QtDesigner instead of Tkinter, you may want to check that out if you don't know about it already).